# Override ScriptControl or BaseValidator for an async ASP.NET validator control?

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-ajax

I'm planning to develop an ASP.NET server control to provide asynchronous username availability validation for new user registrations.  The control will allow a developer to point it at a "username" TextBox and it will provide an indication of whether or not the username is available.  Like [this example](http://encosia.com/2007/07/02/aspnet-username-availability-checking-via-ajax/), but without the clunky UpdatePanel.

One design decision that's giving me headaches is whether to inherit from **ScriptControl** or **BaseValidator**.

By implementing it as a **ScriptControl**, I can make the client side portion easier to deal with and easily localize it with a resx.

However, I want to make sure that the validator functions properly with respect to Page.IsValid.  The only way I know to do this is to override **BaseValidator** and implement `EvaluateIsValid()`.

So, my question is, how would you suggest structuring this control?  Is inheriting from BaseValidator the best (only) way to get the validator part right, or can I do that in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do both if you implement the [IScriptControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.iscriptcontrol.aspx) interface while also deriving from BaseValidator:

```
public class YourControl : IScriptControl, BaseValidator
```

To implement the IScriptControl interface means your control will also have to have the GetScriptReferences and GetScriptDescriptors methods.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.

I started down that road, but tried using override instead of virtual methods for GetScript*, which didn't work.  So, I thought it wasn't possible to implement both together.